# Как привязать купона к пользователю WC?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть 10 созданный купонов типа "fixed_cart", и я хочу после покупки определеннного товара давать клиенту один из 10 купонов, и сохранить его ему как личный купон, никто больше его получить не может. Подскажите каким способом это сделать?
Копал в сторону создания user_meta, но не понимаю как мне рандомно отобрать и исключить потом купон для других

Comment: Используй плагины. Только тут лучше не купоны, а скидки.

Comment: @SeVlad - Фактически промокод в виде 000-000 должен быть, и он на самом сайте ничего не будет делать , он выдается для применения его в магазине лично кассиру, а скидка наверное может влиять на общую стоимость товара/корзины только

Comment: А ты говоришь клиенту после покупки. Кассиру - это совсем другой разговор. Ответ ща напишу. А правила скидок в плагинах могут быть совершено разные.

Answer (score 0):

Если для одного человека (или не одного), то в настройках каждого купона можно указать емейлы покупателя(ей).

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, да такое рассматривал) Но для каждого промокода делать так не будут) Может быть не 10, а 100 промокодов, клиентов каждый день больше становится (

Comment: @Михаил Ты б уже как-то определился - клиенту или кассиру, 10 или 100... Если не подходит стандартное - ищи плагины.